Mathematician and musician
Mathematician and musician,
Studying planets and primes,
Astronomer and theologian,
His name lies in the skies.
In his name are some sequences,
One is quite prestigious.
Another is a mere eight notes,
Although the last’s ambiguous.
Sequence # 1:

Sequence # 2:

Who is he, explain the sequences, and what is the alternate ending to sequence #2?
Prefer no partial answers please.
Hint:

 "..." means that Sequence 1 continues indefinitely and I redacted the rest of it as it is so famous. There is nothing special about the first two notes.

Hint 2:

 This scholar might have been pleased to know that as far as I can tell, his name alone lies in the skies; there is no other.


Strongly considering rot13[xrcyre ('wbunaarf' vf fhfcvpvbhfyl funcrq sbe frdhrapr ahzore gjb) or rhyre] - both seem to fit the first half well as answers. The music part is stumping me.

rot13(guvf vf jung V guvax pyrneyl ertneqvat xrcyre naq uvf nznmvat jbex va nfgebabzl naq gur cynargf (jurer nyy gur cynargf tbg n zhfvpny fpnyr) guebhtu unezbavprf zhaqv). Gur svefg frdhrapr vf n cresrpg svsgu... juvpu eryngrf gb xrcyre'f jbex ohg V pnaabg svaq gur zvffvat pbaarpgvbaf.)

Note: don't worry about the knowledge tag. Once you identify sequence 1 (using your own trivia knowledge or easily found on the web), sequence 2 requires no computers and you can contemplate it as you go about your day.

I can't translate it to notes, but the first two entries seem to match... is the next term of sequence 1 somehow related to rot13(Guvegl-bar)?

@Prim3numbah - certainly (check the title)
